# how to reload activity on Item click of ListView in android

Tags: android

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);


        new OrderData().execute();

        return view;
    }




    class OrderData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                String Response = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(Constant.OrderUL + "2");


                JSONObject _jobjec = new JSONObject(Response);
                OrderModel _orderModel = new OrderModel();


                _orderModel.setJobID(_jobjec.getString("JobID"));
                _orderModel.setCustomerName(_jobjec.getString("CustomerName"));

                _orderModel.setCustomerAddressName(_jobjec.getString("CustomerAddressName"));
                _orderModel.setCustomerPhoneNumber(_jobjec.getString("CustomerPhoneNumber"));
                _orderModel.setCustomerHouseNumber(_jobjec.getString("CustomerHouseNumber"));
                _orderModel.setCustomerArea(_jobjec.getString("CustomerArea"));
                _orderModel.setCustomerLandmark(_jobjec.getString("CustomerLandmark"));
                _orderModel.setCustomerCity(_jobjec.getString("CustomerCity"));
                _orderModel.setServiceType(_jobjec.getString("ServiceType"));
                _orderModel.setQuantity(_jobjec.getString("Quantity"));
                _orderModel.setPayementMethod(_jobjec.getString("PayementMethod"));
                _orderModel.setJobAmount(_jobjec.getString("JobAmount"));
                _orderModel.setJobStatus(_jobjec.getString("JobStatus"));
//                JobStatus =_jobjec.getString("JobStatus");
                orderList.add(_orderModel);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            order_listview.setAdapter(_adapter);
            _adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listitem, orderList);
            order_listview.setAdapter(_adapter);

        }
    }
```

this is my adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OrderModel> {
    // Declare Variables
    Context mcontext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<OrderModel> datamodel;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                           List<OrderModel> worldpopulationlist) {


        super(context, resourceId, worldpopulationlist);
        this.mcontext = context;
        this.datamodel = worldpopulationlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
        TextView textView3;
        TextView textView4;

        TextView status;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
            //
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.textView4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView17);
            holder.status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.aceeptimageview);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        holder.textView1.setText(datamodel.get(position).getJobID() + ":" + datamodel.get(position).getCustomerName());
        holder.textView2.setText(datamodel.get(position).getCustomerPhoneNumber());
        holder.textView3.setText(datamodel.get(position).getCustomerAddressName() + " " +
                        datamodel.get(position).getCustomerLandmark() + " " +
                        datamodel.get(position).getCustomerCity()

        );
        holder.textView4.setText(datamodel.get(position).getServiceType() + " " + datamodel.get(position).getJobAmount());


        String Status = datamodel.get(position).getJobStatus();


        if (Status.equals("Pending")) {
            holder.status.setText("Accept");

            holder.status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    try {
                        holder.status.setText("Started");
                        JSONObject _jobject = new JSONObject();

                        _jobject.put("JobID", datamodel.get(position).getJobID().toString());
                        _jobject.put("Status", "Accepted");
                        new StatsuBackground().execute(_jobject.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        if (Status.equals("Accepted")) {
            holder.status.setText("Started");
            holder.status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    holder.status.setText("Closed");
                    try {
                        JSONObject _jobject = new JSONObject();

                        _jobject.put("JobID", datamodel.get(position).getJobID().toString());
                        _jobject.put("Status", "Started");
                        new StatsuBackground().execute(_jobject.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        if (Status.equals("Started")) {
            holder.status.setText("Closed");
            holder.status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Cloesd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        JSONObject _jobject = new JSONObject();

                        _jobject.put("JobID", datamodel.get(position).getJobID().toString());
                        _jobject.put("Status", "Closed");
                        new StatsuBackground().execute(_jobject.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });
        }


        return view;
    }



    class StatsuBackground extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String Response = PosttoServer.getJSONfromURL(Constant.StatusUrl, params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have applied onItem Click function in adapter each item. What I want when I click on particular item is my activity should reload and hit again api so that I can get updated value from server. How should I apply this so that I can get updated? I even tried notfydatasetchange but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
            public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OrderModel> {
// Declare Variables
Context mcontext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<OrderModel> datamodel;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                       List<OrderModel> worldpopulationlist) {


    super(context, resourceId, worldpopulationlist);
    this.mcontext = context;
    this.datamodel = worldpopulationlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    TextView textView3;
    TextView textView4;

    TextView status;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        //
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.textView4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView17);
        holder.status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.aceeptimageview);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    holder.textView1.setText(datamodel.get(position).getJobID() + ":" + datamodel.get(position).getCustomerName());
    holder.textView2.setText(datamodel.get(position).getCustomerPhoneNumber());
    holder.textView3.setText(datamodel.get(position).getCustomerAddressName() + " " +
                    datamodel.get(position).getCustomerLandmark() + " " +
                    datamodel.get(position).getCustomerCity()

    );
    holder.textView4.setText(datamodel.get(position).getServiceType() + " " + datamodel.get(position).getJobAmount());


    String Status = datamodel.get(position).getJobStatus();


    if (Status.equals("Pending")) {
        holder.status.setText("Accept");

        holder.status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                try {
                    holder.status.setText("Started");
                    JSONObject _jobject = new JSONObject();

                    _jobject.put("JobID", datamodel.get(position).getJobID().toString());
                    _jobject.put("Status", "Accepted");
                    new StatsuBackground().execute(_jobject.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    if (Status.equals("Accepted")) {
        holder.status.setText("Started");
        holder.status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                holder.status.setText("Closed");
                try {
                    JSONObject _jobject = new JSONObject();

                    _jobject.put("JobID", datamodel.get(position).getJobID().toString());
                    _jobject.put("Status", "Started");
                    new StatsuBackground().execute(_jobject.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    if (Status.equals("Started")) {
        holder.status.setText("Closed");
        holder.status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Cloesd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    JSONObject _jobject = new JSONObject();

                    _jobject.put("JobID", datamodel.get(position).getJobID().toString());
                    _jobject.put("Status", "Closed");
                    new StatsuBackground().execute(_jobject.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
    }


    return view;
}



class StatsuBackground extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String Response = PosttoServer.getJSONfromURL(Constant.StatusUrl, params[0]);
        return null;
    }

     @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  //check if success
  finish();
  startActivity(((Activity)context).getIntent())
}


}
```

}

Try this

Comment: ((Activity) context).finish() try this